# How to pass the link to the file (that is located on my computer) into the Docker image?

Tags: docker

I have a small Spring Boot application and a parse controller that parses a .csv file and adds corresponding information to the H2 db:

```
@RestController
public class ParseController {
@Autowired
private CSVFileParserService parser;

@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("/parse")
public String startParsing() {
    parser.parseCsvFile("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\spring-boot-amazon\\src\\main\\resources\\Reviews.csv");
    return "Parsing has been initialized";
}
}
```

As you can see, I pass the direct path to the file that is located on my computer. Everything works as expected right here.
After that, I have tried to create a Docker image for my application and at the moment I have faced a problem on how to make my ParseController work properly.
I have created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

When I run my image and launch the ParseController I get this error message:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-amazon\src\main\resources\Reviews.csv (No such file or directory)

I tried to pass the file directly and tried to put the file into the image, nothing worked. Could you please help me?
P.S. This is my first question on Stackoverflow, hope I did everything right

Comment: How about setting the path as an environment variable (in your app) and according to "in docker" or "in local machine" set the env var. For example- if the file `/.dockerenv` exists, you are in a docker container. Also note that Windows uses backslashes while your docker image might be based on Linux and then it's slashes. Another thing, add the WORKDIR command in your Dockerfile

Comment: @MeirGabay, thanks a lot! Sounds interesting, but may I ask you to be a little bit specific? Do you mean I should put the path to the file to my application.properties file as a variable and then, depending on the environment, I should pass it in the correct format?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly define where the file is located on your local filesystem when running the container. Also, there are some things specific to Windows, more info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume. When you start the container, try adding `-v /path/to/local/file:/tmp`

Comment: Thank you guys, both of you, I have managed to fix that by adding 
COPY src/main/resources/Reviews.csv /tmp/ 
to my Dockerfile and by passing the direct path to this file "/tmp/Reviews.csv" at the controller